# how to solve Uncaught ReferenceError: populate is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, ionic-framework

here is my code.  help me to solve this guys. appreciate all the answer given.

code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function populate(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if (s1.value == "Futsal") {
      var optionArray = ["|", "court a| Court A", "court b|Court B", "court c|Court C"];
    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }
</script>
<label class="item item-select">
  <span class="input-label">Sports</span>
  <select id="sport" name="sport" onchange="populate(this.id,'Court')" ;>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Futsal">Futsal</option>
    <option value="Badminton">Badminton</option>
  </select>
</label>
<label class="item item-select">
  <span class="input-label">Court</span>
  <select id="Court" name="Court"></select>
```

This is giving error ReferenceError: populate is not defined

Comment: Your code works. I made a code snippet and then no error occurs. It must be something outside of your code.

Comment: On the real site is `populate` defined inside another function?

Comment: @Barmar it coded exactly like i showed to you in one html file

Comment: I changed your question to a stack snippet and you can see that it works. There must be something different on your real site.

Comment: Is your site accessible on the Internet?

Comment: im using inspect element by chrome and it said populate not define @barmar

Comment: yup it accessed on the internet

Comment: What is the URL for it?

Comment: oh my bad.. actually this is mobile application not web based.. sorry for misunderstanding . it need to access internet in order to use it. @barmar